# Генератор кода Javascript

Tags: javascript, сервер

Есть генератор кода на JavaScript , который выдает рандомные цифры и буквы для юзера. Как сделать так, чтобы этот код для каждого отдельного юзера выдавался с сервера? То есть чтобы этот скрипт уже заранее был на сервере и каждому ново-зарегистрированному юзеру выдавался новый код. Потому как он есть у меня с формы, но оттуда его можно изменять (чего не должно быть). Поэтому нужно, чтобы с сервера выдавался

```js
$(function() {
  function str_rand() {
    var result = '';
    var words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
    var max_position = words.length - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
      position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
      result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  $("#gen").click(function() {
    $("#short_link").val(str_rand());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label for="first-name">Your code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="code" id="short_link" style="border: 1px solid #3E7EFF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
</li>
<li>
  <div id="gen" style="cursor: pointer" ;>Generate</div>
</li>
```

*Не судите строго, я новичок.*

Comment: Нужно его портировать на сервер, чтобы код выполнялся на сервере.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что нужно делать, так как не известно на чем написан сервер NodeJS, Go, PHP и т.д. На данный момент сервер абстрактный, что породит абстрактный вопрос. Добавьте как можно больше конкретики в ваш вопрос ,чтобы вам смогли дать ответ.

Comment: Каким образом можно портировать код на сервер?

Comment: Действительно интересный вопрос. Неплохо бы на примере показать, как можно портировать код на сервер.